# LINQ, SQLite, grouping and count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I am trying to use SQLite with LINQ on a windows store apps for the first time and I need some help with the following:

I want to return the number of project that is associated to a customer. for example:

- Customer ID 42 has 3 projects with ID(82,83,84), therefore should return 3
- Customer ID 43 has 1 project with ID(26), therefore should return 1

Customer Table

```
ID|Name             |City      |Contact
42|"Adventure Works"|"Bellevue"|"Mu Han"
43|"Contoso"        |"Seattle" |"David Hamilton"
44|"Fabrikam"       |"Redmond" |"Guido Pica"
45|"Tailspin Toys"  |"Kent"    |"Michelle Alexander"
```

Project Table

```
ID|CustomerID|Name                |Description        |Duedate
83|42        |"Expense Reports"   |"Windows Store app"|"2013-11-25 00:00:00"
84|42        |"Time Reporting"    |"Windows Store app"|"2013-12-05 00:00:00"
85|42        |"Project Management"|"Windows Store app"|"2013-12-15 00:00:00"
86|43        |"Soccer Scheduling" |"Windows Phone app"|"2013-11-27 00:00:00"
87|44        |"Product Catalog"   |"MVC4 app"         |"2013-12-21 00:00:00"
88|44        |"Expense Reports"   |"Windows Store app"|"2013-11-18 00:00:00"
89|44        |"Expense Reports"   |"Windows Phone app"|"2014-01-05 00:00:00"
90|45        |"Kids Game"         |"Windows Store app"|"2014-01-20 00:00:00"
```

EDIT: This is the current one I am working with.

```
 var projectcount = ( from x in db.Table<Project>() 
                      group x by x.Id into g 
                      select new { project = g.Key ,Count = g } );
```

and it returns the number 8 which is the total number of projects.

Thank you in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: What do you have so far? What result are you seeing vs. what you're expecting to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You group by the wrong property, try the following code instead:

```
var projectcount = from x in db.Table<Project>()
                   group x by x.CustomerID into g
                   select new { 
                       CustomerID = g.Key,
                       ProjectCount = g.Count()
                   };
```